# How to make division inside division to add image and text?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divisions, header, left, right and footer. I want to again divide header into 2 sections, left header and right header. In right header, I want to keep image in same division I want to mention other options, such as home, about us. Whereas in left division there should be text.

How can I make it with the help of HTML and CSS? Below is the HTML and CSS snippets:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Search Engine Title Goes Here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="container"> </div>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header-left-container">
    <h1>heading1,<br> heading2 and <br>heading3</h1>
    </div>
    <div id=header-right-container>
    <img border="0" src="tra.jpg"  alt="drug"align="right" width="750" height="150">
    </div>
    </div>
   <div id="sidebar"> Left </div>
   <div id="content"> <p></p></div>
   <div id="footer"> </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

CSS code:

```
  body {background: #ffffff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
  a {color: #2b2bf6;}

  #container
  {width: 900px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #dddddd;}

   #header
   {width:1000;
   height: 150px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   background: #FFFFA3;}

   #sidebar
   {width: 200px;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   float: left;
   background: #f0e811;}

  #content
  {width: auto;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  float: left;
  background: #8be0ef;}

  #footer
  {width: auto;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  float: left;
  background: #000000;
  clear:both;}
```

Since I am newbie to web designing, depend on ur kind cooperation.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. If your question is "how do I include other items inside my header-right-container" you simply put them in there, either before or after the `img`. A div can contain as many items as you want, you're not limited to just one item.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

- Make sure to quote your class names
- If you have empty div elements you
  may find they act more predictable by adding `&nbsp;` inside them
- Tags like img and br should be self closing (`<img ... />` and `<br />`
  rather than `<img ...>` and `<br>`)
- Try to keep your indentation consistent, it makes your code easier to maintain and debug
- It's better practice to use CSS styling rather than attempting to align the img element using attributes
- It's better practice to use CSS styling rather than attempting to remove the border of the img element using attributes
- The image element align won't work because it's parent element (#header-right-container) will determine it's position.
- Check whether you want the container div to wrap all of the other elements - If so, also check the width as it's 100px smaller than the header div

This leaves the following HTML code:

```
<div id="container">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-left-container">
        <h1>heading1, <br />heading2 and <br />heading3</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="header-right-container">
        <img src="tra.jpg" alt="drug" width="750" height="150" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">Left</div>
<div id="content"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
<div id="footer">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

- Make sure your width have a unit assigned (For example `width: 1000px;`
- As Dan Goodspeed suggested, add floats to the child header classes
- Keep indentation consistent for ease of maintenance and debugging

Here's the cleaned up code with the suggestions implemented:
http://jsfiddle.net/fD3dN/

Answer (score 0):

You should really only use CSS for the styling, no border="0", width="750", etc.  Dpn't forget to quote your IDs in the HTML.  I see you forgot to quote header-right-container.  Also, in the CSS, if the number is not 0, you have to specify a unit, which you left off of the #header width.  Looking at your code, I'm guessing the issue you're having is that the left and right headers are appearing on top of each other.  There's various ways of handling it depending on the content, but maybe this would help, in your CSS...

```
 #header-left-container { float:left;}
 #header-right-container { float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your HTML and CSS in this pen http://cdpn.io/CgBIu I have also written it with assumption that the container is the wrapper for the code underneath.

You will see I have done all the styling within CSS and kept the HTML very simple, this will keep file sizes down and allow the page to load faster in the future. As previously mentioned check your code for any imperfections such as the "" missing from ID names.

Self closing tags are dependant on which Doctype you are using but it is good practice to close them with />.

You don't need to add a float to both elements, you can add it to the sidebar and then the content will align next to it. No need to write extra code you don't need.